# could not convert the xml to json using java

Tags: java, xml, json, xml-parsing

**i have the xml file, i need to convert into the json.
the json output is the partial convert of the xml, not whole xml is converted..**

Reason you can find the output of the json, only partial is being converted.
remaining portion is omitted.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ASF_Service_ResponseVO typesig="155c0afe34b" id="1">
    <service type="String">OnboardingV2</service>
    <operation type="String">start_onboarding_session</operation>
    <requested_version type="String">1.0</requested_version>
    <actual_version type="String">1.0</actual_version>
    <server_info type="String">onboardingv2serv:start_onboarding_session&amp;CalThreadId=85&amp;TopLevelTxnStartTime=13b40fe91c4&amp;Host=L-BLR-00438534&amp;pid=3564</server_info>
    <result typesig="fff96cab366a5def" type="Onboarding::StartOnboardingSessionResponse" id="2">
        <onboarding_id type="String">137</onboarding_id>
        <success type="bool">true</success>
    </result>
</ASF_Service_ResponseVO>
```

### ConvertXMLtoJSON.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javasample1;

//import net.sf.json.JSON;
//import net.sf.json.JSONObject; 
//import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.XML;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author gopc
 */
    public class ConvertXMLtoJSON{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            try
            {

                File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\gopc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaSample1\\src\\javasample1\\Sample1.xml");
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                StringBuilder builder =  new StringBuilder();
                int ptr = 0;
                while ((ptr = inputStream.read()) != -1 )
                {
                    builder.append((char) ptr);
                }

                String xml  = builder.toString();
                JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml); 
                System.out.println(jsonObj);

                /*
                String xmlString  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><ASF_Service_ResponseVO id=\"1\"><service type=\"String\">OnboardingV2</service><operation type=\"String\">start_onboarding_session</operation><requested_version type=\"String\">1.0</requested_version><actual_version type=\"String\">1.0</actual_version><server_info type=\"String\">onboardingv2serv:start_onboarding_session&amp;CalThreadId=85&amp;TopLevelTxnStartTime=13b40fe91c4&amp;Host=L-BLR-00438534&amp;pid=3564</server_info><result type=\"Onboarding::StartOnboardingSessionResponse\" id=\"2\"><onboarding_id type=\"String\">137</onboarding_id><success type=\"bool\">true</success></result></ASF_Service_ResponseVO>";

                JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString); 
                System.out.println(jsonObj.toString()); 
                */
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

### output

```
run:
{"ASF_Service_ResponseVO":{"server_info":{"content":"onboardingv2serv:start_onboarding_session&CalThreadId=85&TopLevelTxnStartTime=13b40fe91c4&Host=L-BLR-00438534&pid=3564","type":"String"},"result":{"id":2,"typesig":"fff96cab366a5def","onboarding_id":{"content":137,"type":"String"},"type":"Onboarding::StartOnboardingSessionResponse","success":{"content":true,"type":"bool"}},"operation":{"content":"start_onboarding_session","type":"String"},"requested_version":{"content":1,"type":"String"},"service":{"content":"OnboardingV2","type":"String"},"actual_version":{"content":1,"type":"String"}}}
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

The resulting JSON object formated:

```
{
    "ASF_Service_ResponseVO": {
        "server_info": {
             "content":"onboardingv2serv:start_onboarding_session&CalThreadId=85&TopLevelTxnStartTime=13b40fe91c4&Host=L-BLR-00438534&pid=3564",
             "type":"String"
        },
        "result": {
            "id":2,
            "typesig":"fff96cab366a5def",
            "onboarding_id": {
                 "content":137,
                 "type":"String"
            },
            "type":"Onboarding::StartOnboardingSessionResponse",
            "success": {
                "content":true,
                "type":"bool"
            }
        },
        "operation": {
            "content":"start_onboarding_session",
            "type":"String"
        },
        "requested_version":{
            "content":1,
            "type":"String"
        },
        "service":{
            "content":"OnboardingV2",
            "type":"String"},
        }
        "actual_version":{
             "content":1,
             "type":"String"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm.. Are you sure that output is invalid? What is missing?

Comment: I took the liberty of formating the JSON output properly so that one can tell what exactly you are missing. Unfortunately I can't tell at first glance.

Comment: HOW WHY THE ORDER CHANGES...

Comment: The order is not relevant, all the information is there and correctly nested.

Comment: @Gopal: The order is irrelevant for almost all use-cases of JSON. Why do you worry about the order? Also, please don't use allcaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't expect the same order of xml, the following is the output json

```
{
    "ASF_Service_ResponseVO":{
        "server_info":{
            "content":"onboardingv2serv:start_onboarding_session&CalThreadId=85&TopLevelTxnStartTime=13b40fe91c4&Host=L-BLR-00438534&pid=3564",
            "type":"String"
        },
        "id":"1",
        "result":{
            "id":"2",
            "typesig":"fff96cab366a5def",
            "onboarding_id":{
                "content":"137",
                "type":"String"
            },
            "type":"Onboarding::StartOnboardingSessionResponse",
            "success":{
                "content":"true",
                "type":"bool"
            }
        },
        "operation":{
            "content":"start_onboarding_session",
            "type":"String"
        },
        "requested_version":{
            "content":"1.0",
            "type":"String"
        },
        "typesig":"155c0afe34b",
        "service":{
            "content":"OnboardingV2",
            "type":"String"
        },
        "actual_version":{
            "content":"1.0",
            "type":"String"
        }
    }
}
```